# AdjustPan Android doesn't behave as I would expect

Tags: android, react-native

From what I could understand of the difference between AdjustResize and Adjust pan, it's that AdjustResize will change the height of all the components so that they can fit and squeeze into a "half screen" while AdjustPan will, only in the case where a view below the keyboard takes the focus, bring up this particular view so that it is accessible despite the keyboard.

However, in my case, I have a comment section which is a React Navigation view. In this view, I have a TextInput below it that must go up when the keyboard opens to write a comment. But when this TextInput goes up, it takes everything with it, including the elements of the previous view in the stack.

*Picture from comment section (The gray above the keyboard is the textinput)*

[image]

*Picture from previous view in the stack if I go back (Only until the keyboard didblur event is sent and then everything returns to normal)*

[image]

Why does the adjustPan seem to behave a bit like AdjustResize?
I've already tried to set AdjustNothing, but unfortunately it can't work because I don't receive keyboard events anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out where the problem was coming from.

I use
`<SafeAreaInsetContext>`
from the `react-native-safe-area-context` library because I need to do special management of the insets bottom for devices like iPhoneX or iPhone 11.
And in fact, when the Android keyboard opens, the insetBottom is redefined to take the keyboard size as well. So I had a padding on the bottom of my screen that was the size of my keyboard as soon as it opened. So the behavior is normal, and after correction, my AdjustPan behaves exactly as it should !